# How get first name initial and last name in XSLT

Tags: xslt

I want yo get the first name initial and last name.

Input :

```
<root>
  <ele name="Samp Huwani"/>
  <ele name="Gong Gitry"/>
  <ele name="Dery Wertnu"/>
</root>
```

Output

```
<names>S Huwani</name>
<names>G Gitry</name>
<names>D Wertnu</name>
```

Tried Code:

```
<xsl:template match="root/name">
  <names>
    <xsl:value-of select="@name" />
  </name>
</xsl:template>
```

I am using XSLT 2.0 . Thank you

Comment: For a full specification, you need to say what other kinds of values might be found in @name, and how you want them handled. For example, what do you want if it contains "Michael Howard Kay", or if it contains "Sir Norman Foster".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the given example, you could use:

```
<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="ele">
            <name>
                <xsl:value-of select="substring(@name, 1, 1)"/>
                <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(@name, ' ')"/>
            </name>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

However, names often do not conform to the same pattern.

---

In XSLT 2.0, you could simplify(?) this by using regex, e.g.:

```
<xsl:value-of select="replace(@name, '^(.{1}).* (.*)', '$1 $2')"/>
```