# How get first String initial and other Strings as it is

Tags: xslt

I want yo get the first name initial and last name.

Input :

```
<root>
  <ele name="Samp Huwani"/>
  <ele name="Laura McKay (J)"/>
  <ele name="Dery Wertnu"/>
</root>
```

Output

```
<names>S Huwani</name>
<names>L McKay (J)</name>
<names>D Wertnu</name>
```

Tried Code:

```
<xsl:template match="root/ele">
  <names>
    <xsl:value-of select="replace(@name, '^(.{1}).* (.*)', '$1 $2')" />
  </name>
</xsl:template>
```

Result I am getting:

```
<names>S Huwani</name>
<names>L (J)</name>
<names>D Wertnu</name>
```

According to my code, I am getting `L (J)`. it should be `L McKay (J)`. But Other two results are working as expected

I am using XSLT 2.0. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **substring** and **substring-after:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:template match="root/ele">
        <names>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring(@name, 1, 1), ' ', substring-after(@name, ' '))"/>
         </names>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: As was already suggested in the first iteration of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58265023/3016153

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use regex for this, try:

```
<xsl:value-of select="replace(@name, '^(.{1})[^ ]* (.*)', '$1 $2')" />
```